# The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, lista, pandas

sou uma pessoa leiga em programação, na comunidade stackoverflow e não estou conseguindo resolver o seguinte problema:

Criar duas listas(ou se preferir 2 colunas em um Dataframe Novo) em que  busca num Dataframe o sucessor e o antecessor dos elemento que estão outro Datatframe(referência). Eu fiz um código(estou aberto à novas soluções) e está acusando uma mensagem de erro que está no título.

```
antecessor = []
sucessor = []

for elemento in x[0]:
    i = 0
    while i < y[0].size:
        if elemento < y[0].iloc[i:i+1]:
            sucessor.append(y[0].iloc[i:i+1])
            antecessor.append(y[0].iloc[i-1:i])
            break
    i += 1
```

obs:

> i. Os elementos que se encontram nas colunas dos Dataframe X e Y são
> do tipo float
>
> ii. O número de elementos do Dataframe X é menor que do
> Dataframe Y.

Desde já, agradeço pela ajuda e atenção de todos.

Atenciosamente,
Wendel de Oliveira

x.dat (2 colunas)

0.509054    0.0767
0.355404    0.0769
0.279519    0.0771
0.219150    0.0773
0.176476    0.0775
0.151162    0.0777
0.139228    0.0779
0.117106    0.0781
0.108191    0.0783
0.095156    0.0785

y.dat (4 colunas)

0.0893015 1.00584 0.0725685 -1.83063
0.0938015 1.00614 0.0642253 -1.87747
0.0983015 1.00641 0.0556713 -1.9243
0.102801 1.00664 0.0469066 -1.97114
0.107301 1.00684 0.0379312 -2.01797
0.111801 1.00699 0.0287449 -2.06481
0.116301 1.00709 0.0193479 -2.11165
0.120801 1.00716 0.00974018 -2.15848
0.125301 1.00718 -7.83241e-05 -2.20532
0.129801 1.00716 -0.0101076 -2.25215
0.134301 1.00709 -0.0203476 -2.29899
0.138801 1.00697 -0.0307984 -2.34582
0.143301 1.00681 -0.0414599 -2.39266
0.147801 1.0066 -0.0523322 -2.43949
0.152301 1.00634 -0.0634153 -2.48632
0.156801 1.00603 -0.0747091 -2.53316
0.161301 1.00567 -0.0862136 -2.57999
0.165801 1.00525 -0.0979289 -2.62682
0.170301 1.00479 -0.109855 -2.67365
0.174801 1.00426 -0.121992 -2.72048
0.179301 1.00369 -0.134339 -2.76731
0.183801 1.00305 -0.146897 -2.81414
0.188301 1.00236 -0.159666 -2.86097
0.192801 1.00162 -0.172646 -2.90779
0.197301 1.00081 -0.185836 -2.95462
0.201801 0.999944 -0.199237 -3.00144
0.206301 0.999017 -0.212849 -3.04826
0.210801 0.998028 -0.226672 -3.09508
0.215301 0.996977 -0.240705 -3.14189
0.219801 0.995861 -0.254949 -3.18871
0.224301 0.994682 -0.269403 -3.23552
0.228801 0.993436 -0.284068 -3.28233
0.233301 0.992124 -0.298944 -3.32913
0.237801 0.990745 -0.31403 -3.37593
0.242301 0.989298 -0.329327 -3.42273
0.246801 0.987781 -0.344835 -3.46953
0.251301 0.986194 -0.360553 -3.51632
0.255801 0.984535 -0.376481 -3.56311
0.260301 0.982805 -0.392621 -3.6099
0.264801 0.981001 -0.40897 -3.65669
0.269301 0.979124 -0.425531 -3.70347
0.273801 0.977171 -0.442302 -3.75026
0.278301 0.975143 -0.459283 -3.79705
0.282801 0.973037 -0.476475 -3.84383
0.287301 0.970854 -0.493877 -3.89062
0.291801 0.968592 -0.51149 -3.93741
0.296301 0.96625 -0.529314 -3.98421
0.300801 0.963828 -0.547348 -4.03101
0.305301 0.961323 -0.565593 -4.07782
0.309801 0.958737 -0.584048 -4.12464
0.314301 0.956067 -0.602715 -4.17146
0.318801 0.953312 -0.621591 -4.2183
0.323301 0.950472 -0.640679 -4.26515
0.327801 0.947545 -0.659978 -4.31201
0.332301 0.944532 -0.679487 -4.35889
0.336801 0.941429 -0.699208 -4.40577
0.341301 0.938238 -0.719139 -4.45268
0.345801 0.934957 -0.739282 -4.4996
0.350301 0.931584 -0.759635 -4.54654
0.354801 0.92812 -0.7802 -4.59349
0.359301 0.924562 -0.800977 -4.64046
0.3638 0.92091 -0.821964 -4.68745
0.3683 0.917164 -0.843164 -4.73446
0.3728 0.913321 -0.864574 -4.78149
0.3773 0.909382 -0.886197 -4.82853
0.3818 0.905345 -0.908031 -4.8756
0.3863 0.901209 -0.930077 -4.92268
0.3908 0.896974 -0.952335 -4.96978
0.3953 0.892638 -0.974805 -5.0169
0.3998 0.8882 -0.997487 -5.06404
0.4043 0.88366 -1.02038 -5.1112
0.4088 0.879017 -1.04349 -5.15837
0.4133 0.874268 -1.06681 -5.20556
0.4178 0.869415 -1.09034 -5.25277
0.4223 0.864455 -1.11408 -5.29999
0.4268 0.859388 -1.13804 -5.34723
0.4313 0.854212 -1.16221 -5.39448
0.4358 0.848927 -1.18659 -5.44175
0.4403 0.843532 -1.21118 -5.48903
0.4448 0.838026 -1.23599 -5.53632
0.4493 0.832408 -1.26101 -5.58363
0.4538 0.826677 -1.28624 -5.63095
0.4583 0.820831 -1.31169 -5.67827
0.4628 0.814871 -1.33735 -5.72561
0.4673 0.808795 -1.36322 -5.77295
0.4718 0.802602 -1.3893 -5.8203
0.4763 0.796291 -1.4156 -5.86766
0.4808 0.789861 -1.44211 -5.91502
0.4853 0.783311 -1.46883 -5.96238
0.4898 0.776641 -1.49577 -6.00975
0.4943 0.769849 -1.52292 -6.05713
0.4988 0.762934 -1.55029 -6.1045
0.5033 0.755896 -1.57786 -6.15188
0.5078 0.748733 -1.60565 -6.19925
0.5123 0.741445 -1.63366 -6.24663
0.5168 0.73403 -1.66187 -6.29401
0.5213 0.726487 -1.6903 -6.34139
0.5258 0.718817 -1.71894 -6.38877
0.5303 0.711016 -1.7478 -6.43615
0.5348 0.703086 -1.77687 -6.48353
0.5393 0.695024 -1.80615 -6.53091

Comment: Se uma das respostas abaixo resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, escolha a que você mais gostou e marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique à vontade para comentar.

Answer (score 3):

O erro **"The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()"** ocorre quando o python não consegue fazer uma comparação porque o teste lógico não ficou claro. Por exemplo, o seguinte código replicável também retorna esse erro:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                'B': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
                'C': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']})

if 3< df['A'].iloc[0:2]:
    print('ok')
```

Olhando o seu código, parece que esse erro ocorre na expressão `elemento < y[0].iloc[i:i+1]` já que você está comparando um número com uma lista. O python não sabe qual número usar na comparação e retorna o erro.

Comment: Pensei que estivesse comparando com elemento que está na lista y[0] que está no posição y[0].iloc[i:i+1]

Comment: Não. Pq vc está fazendo um slicing usando ':' em um vetor unidimensional. Talvez vc tenha confundido o operador ':' com ','. Veja esse guia: https://medium.com/horadecodar/data-science-tips-02-como-usar-loc-e-iloc-no-pandas-fab58e214d87

Comment: Lucas eu li aqui. Concordo com que você disse. Faz sentido. 
Você saberia me dizer como faço para buscar o numero de uma lista para fazer essa comparação que pretendo fazer (número com número) ?

Comment: Listas são um exemplo de objetos sequenciais em python. Entre outras propriedades, objetos sequenciais aceitam o operador de subscrito. Isso significa que para acessar, por exemplo, o terceiro elemento de uma lista a = [1,2,3,4], basta fazer a[2] (python começa a contar do zero). Mais detalhes aqui (em eng): https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Sequences

Comment: Beleza. Então transformando as colunas dos dataframe em lista resolve meu o problema. Vou fazer isso agora. Te passo o feedback do resultado. Muito obrigado por estar compartilhando seu tempo e conhecimento comigo.